how to reduce Intellij-IDEA memory footpring even for small projects
I have small project here of less than 100 kLOC of source code. Yet Intellij idea is lagging when I click on main menu or change file. When I raised the memory from 8 gigabytes to 12 gigabytes, the situation seems to be acceptable again. I still can give much more RAM to idea, sure, but I think I should not need that much.
What could be the process to prevent this and make editor responsible? I don't have enabled more than 5 plugins and most of default ones are disabled. Caches are regularly fully cleaned, because idea keeps corrupting them.
IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-241.15989.150, built on April 29, 2024
Licensed to ……

Runtime version: 17.0.10+1-b1207.14 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 6.8.0-40-generic
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 12192M
Cores: 12
Non-Bundled Plugins:
  net.sf.opk.avro-schema-support (223.3.1)
  com.jetbrains.space (241.15989.9)
  org.turbanov.run.configuration.as.action (3.0)
  org.jetbrains.plugins.go-template (241.14494.150)
  net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv (3.4.0-241)
  io.codearte.props2yaml (1.0.2)
  com.jetbrains.jax.ws (241.14494.158)
  String Manipulation (9.14.1)
  PlantUML integration (7.10.1-IJ2023.2)
  org.asciidoctor.intellij.asciidoc (0.42.2)
  MetricsReloaded (1.12)
  com.jetbrains.packagesearch.intellij-plugin (241.0.11)
  com.dmarcotte.handlebars (241.14494.150)
Kotlin: 241.15989.150-IJ
Current Desktop: X-Cinnamon

